# CSV tools for terminal?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, csv

I'm using **Ubuntu 18.04 and above**, both desktop and server, and looking for terminal tools to query / write to large CSV file efficiently, and also easy to interact (few simple commands or commands that resemble SQL query language).

What would you recommend?

Comment: [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/)

Comment: If you want to use *actual* SQL queries, then you can use `csvsql` from [the csvkit package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/csvkit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There a lot of great tools:

- awk
- miller https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
- xsv https://github.com/BurntSushi/xsv
- csvtk https://bioinf.shenwei.me/csvtk/
- VisiData https://www.visidata.org/

Comment: I would prefer to avoid 'awk', although it may help doing basic queries - manipulating data in CSV files using it is quite inconvenient (for me, at least).

Answer (score 3):

One such tool is [csvtool](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/csvtool.1.html), bundled with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 22.10, at least.

NB: Recommending `awk` (as top response in the first answer) is a terrible idea. Indeed, `awk` allows convenient splitting at any defined separator symbol, but if this is `,`, it is very likely to get distracted by any `,` used within CSV values, so you cannot guarantee you get the right columns. The same is true for other low-level tools such as `cut`, etc. There are good reasons to work with these (e.g., cross-platform availability), but if you're going that route, better use TSV rather than CSV files to avoid the field separator issue.

Answer (score 2):

An excellent suit of tools to clean and process csv files is :

https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

The link provides installation  guides and tutorials to get you started.